# Comparing two strings, limited via bitmask in PHP

Tags: php, string, bitmask

In some PHP I need to compare two strings, but only on the bits that are set as one in the bitmask. How would I implement such a behavior?

I've tried:

```
$string1='aaabbb';
$string2='ababbb';
$bitmask='101101';
function compare($string1, $string2, $bitmask){
    $resultBitmask=(~($string1 ^ $string2)|~$bitmask);
}
```

For clarity's sake, I've written `ff` bytes as `1` in the bitmask for illustrative purposes. They would actually be `ff` in hex when a bitmask is generated. Same goes for `0` being null bytes.

The string and the bitmask are always different lengths each time the function is called. I've managed to get a set of bits for comparison, but am unable to check whether they are all set since the lenths differ. At this time, I've been using `preg_match` with a regex that matches any number of `ff` bytes, but is there a more elegant solution?

Edit: Since the strings are any length up to 4096 bits long, they cannot be converted to numbers.

Comment: I think you would have to convert them to numbers.

Comment: @jarchuleta I would, but they can be up to 4 KB.

Comment: you might to find a large number library. or convert them a byte at time then compare.

Comment: @jarchuleta The code is fully portable to web hosts that may not have giant number libraries. As to the second idea, can you add a full answer regarding that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self-solved:

Since this will repeat with many strings of the same length during a run, but have different lengths between runs, I need to check that the resulting string after the bitwise operations is all ones and the correct length. I realized that this string full of ones can be generated when needed, which is quite rarely, once every 1000 or so string comparisons. I can generate the string before runs as follows:

```
$ones=str_repeat(chr(255), $byte_length);
```

and then defining the `compare(` function a bit differently:

```
function compare($string1, $string2, $bitmask){
    global $ones;
    $resultBitmask=(~($string1 ^ $string2)|~$bitmask);
    if ($resultBitmask=$ones){
         return 1;
    } else {return 0};
}
```

The trick was the `str_repeat` which I was not aware of before.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the flashest way of doing it but:

```
$stillTheSame = true;
for($i=0;$i<=strlen($bitmask); $i++)
{
  if($bitmask[$i] == 1)
  {
    if($string1[$i] != $string2[$i]) 
    {
      $stillTheSame = false;
      break;
    }  
  }
}
```

Not sure fof your actual checking logic, but this should help hopefully.

Comment: Isn't that more traversal than recursion? But still, I hav to work with other devs and often would rather write something easily readable than have to explain it to everyone everytime they look at it. Anything for an easy life..

Comment: Sorry, my bad with the terminology. It is indeed traversal.

Comment: This is a good answer, but unfortunately, it seems to take over a second for 1000 iterations with a 160 byte string. Sorry.

Comment: Not built for speed, true. Is it always 1 bitmask for 2 strings, or 1 bitecode for comparing a lot of strings?

Comment: Re: Your last comment. I've rewritten some surrounding code so the same bitmask applies to a lot of strings, but between every run of thousands of strings, it will need a new bitmask and length.

Comment: I was only asking because I thought you may be able to initially go through the mask, make an array of the `strpos` of each '1' and then use that to directly reference the string1/2 char positions that are required. But I still don't think that's quite what you're looking for. Just *potentially* speeds up my slow version. I might have a look at your question again trying to use the bitwise stiff, I'm incredibly rusty with it.

Comment: I actually found a solution. See below, and thanks for the help!